# Display all data in the model and use checkbox to bulk edit all the data

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I am trying to create a page that can allow user to use check boxes edit multiple row of data. I know js can finish the job but I only have limited knowledge about js.. Is there a way to use Django Form and Widgets to accomplish this?

Answer (score 0):

It's certainly possible to use Django-filters (or just a ListView with a fixed QuerySet) to generate a multi-row HTML form complete with checkboxes. Once the user has filtered out what he wants to update, he'll click checkboxes, fill in some fields on the rows, and click on the form-submit button (which you'll have to code in the template) instead of the filter button.

The form data gets POSTed back to the URL you code, and your view then has to loop over the rows represented as raw `request.POST` data. If the checkbox is checked, you can gather the rest of the submitted raw data for that row from `request.POST` into a `dict` with the right keys  for feeding into a Django form. Validate and save in the usual way.

In other words, you are using your form purely to validate. not to generate any html at all. You need greater HTML skill to write that the view template that renders as a form, but no JS is involved (other than appropriate classes and divs for Bootstrap or whatever overall scheme you are using).

It's not the same as a Django form, in that it's pretty hard to re-display the form with what the user typed pre-filled for fixing up  after validation fails. Best if the user is updating stuff that "can't be wrong" such as Yes/No options or comment fields.

You need to consider your database integrity, should the N'th row fails to validate. If the rows are all independent it may be sufficient to tell the user which updates failed. Otherwise you may want to make it a transaction that you can completely roll back on failure.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! I guess I am not so familiar with html form post as well.. I am using datatables to displace the data, since it doesn't need me to write extra js or css to format the data and it has a powerful search function. I also able to find out a jQuery from https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/, which allow me to add checkboxes(forget to mention in the question, I do need a select all checkbox, which I think need js). I am confused about how to get corresponding checkboxes from submit.. Do you have any suggestion?

Comment: I am reading https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Forms. It seems has the answer I want. Do you have any other suggestions? Thanks!